# Question deleted without notice

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question about journalistic responsibility, it's been deleted (doesn't show up in my questions). What has happened?

Comment: Re. your question "How are they allowed to do this" part of the answer might be [Freedom of the press in the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_the_press_in_the_United_States) ... if you want to ask questions like that, [the Politics.SE site](http://politics.stackexchange.com/) might be an on-topic place to do that.

Comment: Please read the [Welcome to Skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) topic: note that topics on this site must be questions asking for evidence about notable claims. A question like "What's the evidence that ...?" is on-topic here, but "How ...?" and "Why ...?" are usually not on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we crossed paths. I deleted [the question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26456/how-can-fox-news-be-allowed-to-say-such-daft-things), and before I finished posting the reasons, you had already asked this question. The original question now has a comment on it explaining that the question is (way) off-topic.

I took longer than normal, because I started to write a comment that included a pointer to the US Constitution, but then I decided that would be a pseudo-answer, which we aren't fond of, and changed my mind.

Comment: WTF, you chose not to give me any information at all over giving me some information?

Comment: Back to the decent SE sites for me.

Comment: I was also worried that explaining that the USA had a First Amendment might be seen as patronising.

Comment: I would imagine the US has a trades description act, you cannot lie about products, you can regulate and have freedom of speech.

Comment: Perhaps you should [commit to Law.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) to find a place to discuss that.